# Mongodb - Create entry to a extisting collection field array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, typescript

So I have a problem with my `var array` to add a new chapter, how would I go about this would I have to do this:

```
array.push({
            chapter: [
                {
                    id: 2,
                    title: 'adsf',
                    content: '',
                    authorNotes: 'asdf'
                }
            ]
        });
```

**RiTest.ts**

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

const Scheme = mongoose.Schema;

export const RiTestScheme = new Scheme({
    novelName: String,
    novelAuthor: String,
    novelCoverArt: String,
    novelTags: Array,
    chapters: [
        {
            id: Number,
            title: String,
            content: String,
            authorNotes: String
        }
    ]
});

export class RiTestController {
    public addChapter(callback: (data) => void) {
        var chapterInfoModel = mongoose.model('ChaptersTest', RiTestScheme);

        var array = [
        {
            chapter: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    title: 'prolog',
                    content: 'conetntt is empty',
                    authorNotes: 'nothing is said by author'
                },
                {
                    id: 1,
                    title: 'making a sword',
                    content: 'mine craft end chapter',
                    authorNotes: 'nothing'
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

        let newChapterInfo = new chapterInfoModel(array);

        newChapterInfo.save((err, book) => {
            if (err) {
                return callback(err);
            } else if (!err) {
                return callback(book);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, `var array` doesn't get saved into `let newChapterInfo = new chapterInfoModel(array);` what I am trying to do add another chapter to `array.chapter` but the array doesn't get recognized in the `chapterInfoModel()` how would I fix this array and add an item to the array to create a new entry into this existing collection

thank for taking your time to answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to insert array of document to your collections, That the reason its not inserting into your collection.

[Document.prototype.save()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-save) will insert only one document to your collection depends on your definition. So to insert `chapter` here is the code below,

```
//array as Object
var array = {
    chapter: [
        {
            id: 0,
            title: 'prolog',
            content: 'conetntt is empty',
            authorNotes: 'nothing is said by author'
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            title: 'making a sword',
            content: 'mine craft end chapter',
            authorNotes: 'nothing'
        }
    ]
};

//Push to your chapter array
array.chapter.push({
    id: 2,
    title: 'adsf',
    content: '',
    authorNotes: 'asdf'
});

let newChapterInfo = new chapterInfoModel(array);
```